# Get select box option before the currently selected option

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have a select box that will be used for some backend sorting. Below I give a visual representation of what the new order will look like by having the item to be sorted in the middle and the currently selected item (in this scheme) after.

I need a way to get the text of the previous option (so the option directly before the currently selected option) so I can populate the before item text. How can I do that?

```
<p>Select an item in the following list that you want this item to go <i>before</i>.</p>
<select name="order-list" id="order-list" class="form-control">
    {array_to_select($list)}
</select>
<p class="m-t-md">Presentation order after changes:</p>
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" id="sortable-item-before">Before Item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" id="sortable-item-current">{$current_item}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" id="sortable-item-after">After Item</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var before = $('#sortable-item-before');
        var after = $('#sortable-item-after');
        $('#order-list').on('change', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            after.html($(this).find('option:selected').text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Example list option:

`<option value="68">Some option</option>`

** values cannot be assumed to be sequential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the index of the selected option, subtract 1 from that, and use it to get the previous option.

```
var index = this.selectedIndex;
if (index > 0) {
    var prevOption = $(this).find("option").eq(index-1);
} else {
    prevOption = null;
}
```

Comment: works great! just modified `$(this).find("option").eq(index-1).text()`